# Create vTiger Sales Order fails due to MANDATORY_FIELDS_MISSING "message":"Mandatory Fields Missing

Tags: web-services, api, vtiger

I'm trying to create a SalesOrder via WebServices but it always fails due to missing mandatory fields.

I'm sending the following fields.

The error message does not specify the missing fields

I'm using vTiger 6.0.0

How can I figure it out

```
              salesOrder.subject = fullDescription
                salesOrder.sostatus = "delivered"
                salesOrder.account_id ='11x28'
                salesOrder.bill_street = shipping.address.street
                salesOrder.bill_city = shipping.address.city
                salesOrder.bill_state = shipping.address.state
                salesOrder.bill_code = shipping.address.postalCode
                salesOrder.bill_country = shipping.address.postalCode

                salesOrder.ship_street = shipping.address.street
                salesOrder.ship_city = shipping.address.city
                salesOrder.ship_state = shipping.address.state
                salesOrder.ship_code = shipping.address.postalCode
                salesOrder.ship_country = shipping.address.postalCode

                salesOrder.invoicestatus = "Created"
                salesOrder.productid = selectedServices[0].id
                salesOrder.quantity = 1
                salesOrder.listprice = selectedServices[0].unit_price

                //
                salesOrder.comment= ""
                salesOrder.tax1 = ""
                salesOrder.tax2 = "10.000"
                salesOrder.tax3 = "6.000"
                salesOrder.pre_tax_total = "876.00"
                salesOrder.currency_id = "21x1"
                salesOrder.conversion_rate = "1.000"
                salesOrder.tax4 = ""

                salesOrder.duedate = "2014-12-12"
                salesOrder.carrier = "FedEx"
                salesOrder.pending = ""
                salesOrder.txtAdjustment = "-21.00000000"
                salesOrder.salescommission = "5.000"
                salesOrder.exciseduty = "0.000"
                salesOrder.hdnGrandTotal = "995.16000000"
                salesOrder.hdnSubTotal = "876.00000000"
                salesOrder.hdnTaxType = "group"
                salesOrder.hdndiscountamount = "0"
                salesOrder.hdnS_H_Percent = "21"
                salesOrder.discount_percent = "25.000"
                salesOrder.discount_amount = ""
                salesOrder.terms_conditions = "- Unless "
                salesOrder.enable_recurring = "0"
```

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the LineItems. Please notice that it has to be CamelCase

```
"LineItems": [
    {
        "productid": "25x142",
        "listprice": "299.00000000",
        "quantity": "1"
    }
],
```

Comment: Took me forever to find this, thanks!  Also works for `PurchaseOrder` types.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the mandatory field "Assigned TO"

Comment: Harshamullangi, my bad on posting the question. I fill in this field in another part of the code. This is not the missing field. It might be related to custom field, but I didn't figure it out yet.